# Bootstrap resources are not loaded in unit tests

Tags: zend-framework

What I am trying to do is to get instance of Doctrine EM (using Bisna Library to load it) in unit test. I can get the instance in controller/model when it's running in 'normal' (not unit testing) mode. And I am going insane of comparing line-by-line code with project where it works :(

Unit test:

```
<?php
class Application_Models_UserTest extends PHPUNit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $_em;
    protected $_model;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        $this->_em = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $this->_model = new Application_Model_User();
        parent::setUp();
        //$this->_em = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        //$this->_model = new Application_Model_User();
    }
```

I get:

```
1) Application_Models_UserTest::testGetByEmailExists
Zend_Exception: No entry is registered for key 'doctrine'

/var/www/html/social_test/library/vendor/Zend/Registry.php:147
/var/www/html/social_test/tests/application/models/UserTest.php:10
```

As you can see from commented lines, I tried (being desperate) to get doctrine EM instance after parent::setUp() call, unsuccessfully. Thought that parent::setUp() finishes initializing app and it might help.

I am running it with `phpunit -c phpunit.xml`. phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./application</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
        <directory>./library</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../library</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./public/report" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight = "true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Unit testing bootstrap.php is also standard and untouched. Plugin path is specified in application.ini and it's in production section (so it's inherited in testing section).
ZF version 1.11.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (taken from ZendCast [Many-to-Many with Doctrine 2](http://code.google.com/p/zendcasts/source/browse/trunk/zc70-many-to-many-with-doctrine-2?spec=svn61&r=61))

```
    class ModelTestCase
        extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        /**
         *
         * @var \Bisna\Application\Container\DoctrineContainer
         */
        protected $doctrineContainer;


      public function setUp()
    {
        global $application;
        $application->bootstrap();
        $this->doctrineContainer = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine');

        $em = $this->doctrineContainer->getEntityManager();
        $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
        $tool->dropDatabase();
        $tool->createSchema($em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata());

        parent::setUp();
    }
```

Bootstrap.php for the unit tests looks like this:

```
<?php
    // Define path to application directory
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
       || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));

    // Define application environment
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');

    // Ensure library/ is on include_path
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
       realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
       get_include_path()
    )));


    /** Zend_Application */
    require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
    require_once 'ModelTestCase.php';
    require_once 'ControllerTestCase.php';
    // Create application, bootstrap, and run
    $application = new Zend_Application(
       APPLICATION_ENV,
       APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
    );
    //$application->bootstrap();
    clearstatcache();
```